# Почему в словосочетании "вечно болтающий язык" — три слова, а в "свежемороженый фарш" — два?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, сложные-слова

Есть ли какое-то правило, которое объяснит это? Почему в первом случае нельзя написать слитно, а во втором раздельно?

А "душераздирающий"?

Comment: А в чем разница между "вечнозеленый" и "вечно зеленый"? Зачем два варианта нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При решении задачи нужно использовать **словарь, грамматику, правила.**

**СЛОЖНОЕ СЛОВО:** ***свежемороженый***

1. **Словари**

**СВЕЖЕМОРОЖЕНЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. =Свежезамороженный. С-ая рыба. С-ые ягоды.

**СВЕЖЕ.**., первая часть **сложных слов**. Обозначает: только что, недавно добытый, приготовленный, сделанный, происшедший. Свежежареный, свежевспаханный, свежевыбеленный, свежевыбритый, свежевымытый, свежезасеянный,  и т.п.
словари

Русский орфографический словарь: свеже... – **первая часть сложных слов**, пишется слитно.

2. **Грамматика:** способ образования слова: сложение двух основ + интерфикс (соед. гласная) ***Е***.
3. **Правило:** **[ПАС § 130](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=70#pp70)**   1. Пишутся **слитно** прилагательные, образованные из основ слов, отношение между которыми носит **подчинительный** характер, напр.: железнодорожный (железная дорога), каменноугольный (каменный уголь), сельскохозяйственный, меднорудный, горнолыжный, водноспортивный и др.

По этому же правилу: ***душераздирающий*** (раздирающий душу).

**СЛОВОСОЧЕТАНИЕ: *вечно болтающий язык***

1. **Словари**

**ВЕЧНЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -чен, -чна, -чно. **Вечно, нареч.** Ничто не существует в. Любить, помнить в. (высок.; всю жизнь). **В. живые** (высок.; о погибших). В.

2. **Грамматика**

Связь примыкание, болтающий (как долго?) вечно.

3. **Правило**

**[ПАС § 131](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=70#pp70):** Пишутся раздельно словосочетания, состоящие из наречия и прилагательного или причастия, напр.: абсолютно необходимый, диаметрально противоположный, жизненно важный и т. п.

**Примечание.** Прилагательные типа ***вечнозелёный***, сильнодействующий, являющиеся терминами, представляют собой слово-сращение, образовавшееся из сочетания наречия с последующим прилагательным или причастием.

Их следует отличать **от свободных сочетаний наречий с причастиями или прилагательными**, пишущихся раздельно. Ср., напр.: быстродействующие средства и быстро действующий в экстремальных ситуациях человек. См. также § 131.

**Сравним** термин и свободное словосочетание:

**ВЕЧНОЗЕЛЁНЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. Не сбрасывающий листвы; остающийся с зелёной листвой, хвоей в течение всего года (о растениях).

***Вечно** молодой город, быстро текущая река, постоянно хмурый человек.*

При решении орфограммы основное внимание уделяется характеристике значения и формы **наречия** (чтобы доказать, что это наречие!). Наречия, обозначающие **о т н о ш е н и е,** в котором рассматривается признак, содержат различные **дополнительные сведения**: прямо пропорциональный, обратно пропорциональный, постоянно хмурый.

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что вечно болтающий язык - частный признак чьего-то языка, в то время как свежемороженый - это название технологии хранения пищевых продуктов(свежевыжатый сок также). Душераздирающий, слова дУше -нет, и наречия такого нет, приходится слитно писать, раздельно было бы "душу раздирающий". Ну и соединительная е в двух последних случаях, а в первом вечно - входит в состав слова, образуя наречие.

Answer (score 0):

По большому счёту правило выглядит так: если есть две характеристики определяемого слова (журнально-газетный киоск), то пишется через дефис, если одна характеристика является характеристикой другой характеристики, то пишется раздельно (демонстративно небрежная причёска), а всё остальное – это просто исключения, коих очень много. ‟Вечно болтающий язык” – характеристика характеристики, ‟свежемороженный фарш” – характеристика характеристики, но исключение, ‟душераздирающий” – не тот случай, а образование от причастия и существительного (раздирающий душу), которые пишутся слитно.